# Getting USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS error when downloading Signer data

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using Docusign's [C# client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) as the basis for my API app and I am sporadically getting USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS when calling the ListTabs function for a document Signer.

Docusign support thought this was because I was trying to pull Tabs for a CC recipient but I have verified that I was only trying to get the Tabs for the Signer.

I have successfully downloaded approximately 700 envelopes with the exact same app and no changes whatsoever to the code but there are about 20 envelopes that throw this error. This makes me believe that this is something internal to Docusign but they have been unable to come up with a root cause.

Has anyone come across a similar issue and been able to resolve it?

Comment: Are you the sender of all these envelopes? Is it possible that the 20 envelopes were sent from a different account? Are you able to login to the Docusign console and access these envelopes?

Comment: I am not the sender but the account I'm using has admin rights and has the checkbox checked in the preferences that gives me rights to the envelopes. This entire process is automated and does not change in any way from envelope to envelope. The successful ones have the same sender and recipient as the envelopes that fail.

Comment: Are all the envelopes in the same state?  Can you provide an envelope Id the was succesfull and another one that failed.

Comment: Yes, all are in the same state, I can access the PDF successfully with docusign.com and I can even pull some of the Tabs using Docusign Retrieve on the failing envelopes. The only difference between the envelopes is who is signing the PowerForm. 

I've provided many envelope IDs, both successful and failing. They now think it's related to a known bug (bug # TT-36) so I'm waiting to see if it's fixed when they release the update. 

Feel free to check my case: # 03073341.